# how to get unicode string from excel

Tags: c++, excel, visual-c++, unicode

Hi i am using ExcelFormat Library to extract some content from a excel file (.xls) which it contains some unicode characters here is the code

```
BasicExcel xls(from);

XLSFormatManager fmt_mgr(xls);
BasicExcelWorksheet* sheet = xls.GetWorksheet(0);

CellFormat fmt_general(fmt_mgr);

fmt_general.set_format_string("0.000");

for (int y = 0; y<2; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x<2; ++x) {

        BasicExcelCell* cell = sheet->Cell(y, x);

        cout << sheet->Cell(y, x)->GetWString();

        CellFormat fmt(fmt_mgr, cell);

        const Workbook::Font& font = fmt_mgr.get_font(fmt);
        string font_name = stringFromSmallString(font.name_);

        const wstring& fmt_string = fmt.get_format_string();

        cell->SetFormat(fmt_general);

        cout << endl;
    }
}

cout << "write: " << from << endl;
xls.SaveAs(to);
```

this code works well and it copies the excel file correctly with unicode characters but before saving data to the new file i need to do some operations on it if the string wasn't in unicode i could use this

```
sheet->Cell(y, x)->GetString();
```

and it works fine but when i have unicode data i can not read it even with

```
sheet->Cell(y, x)->GetWString();
```

because it returns some number and i can't work with it how should i convert the result of GetWstring to appropriate text format

Comment: Try putting the result into a variable: `wchar_t* foo = sheet->Cell(y, x)->GetWString();` Then see what you find in there.  At some index there should be 16-bit chars (eg: 00 65).  Hopefully your debugger will even show the string contents.

Comment: @ebyrob this will still give error

Comment: How could storing a return variable cause an error?  Is this a compile or runtime error?  What is the error you are getting?

Comment: it seems that is returning unicode characters null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging some other libraries i found [libxl](http://www.libxl.com/) a good and compatible with unicode and other languages it has some good examples in the package you download and if you are new to this library i suggest using that a basic code in libxl will be like this

```
#include "libxl.h"
using namespace libxl;

int main() 
{
    Book* book = xlCreateBook(); // xlCreateXMLBook() for xlsx
    if(book)
    {
        Sheet* sheet = book->addSheet(L"Sheet1");
        if(sheet)
        {
            sheet->writeStr(2, 1, L"Hello, World !");
            sheet->writeNum(3, 1, 1000);
        }
        book->save(L"example.xls");
        book->release();
    } 
}
```

but this library isn't free you can parse 100 cells or rows i think but not more it's available for linux windows and mac

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << sheet->Cell(y, x)->GetWString();
```

`GetWString` returns `wchar_t*`. `cout` doesn't know what to do with that - you should be using `wcout` instead.

Comment: i know that i shouldn't use cout but when i use wcout i will get an exception for access violation and by appropriate text format i mean that printing the string as it is in the excel file

Comment: @ZiDoM If I remember correctly there can be some problems with `wcout` depending on project settings and mixing with `cout`.  I believe `wprintf()` mixes better.

Comment: @ZiDoM Did you check for a `NULL` ie: `0` return from `GetWString()`?  Otherwise, it should be a valid `wchar_t*` according to the specification.

Comment: @ebyrob yes its null but it shouldn't be when i put some english text in the excel file all things are right but when unicode comes it returns null

Answer (score 1):

From the closest thing to an API I could find:

```
const wchar_t* GetWString() const   Get an Unicode string. Returns 0 if cell 
                                    does not contain an Unicode string.
```

From the Article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13852/BasicExcel-A-Class-to-Read-and-Write-to-Microsoft

Comment: thanks for your help i think this library doesn't support arabic or persian